# I want to use javascript to insert an attribute to an element

Tags: javascript, html

Any ideas how I would go about writing a javascript method to insert an attribute to a tag

eg. I have

```
<input id='in1' value='Submit' type='submit'/>
```

and I want to insert an attribute name

```
<input id='in1' name='submit_content' value='Submit' type='submit'/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("in1").setAttribute("name", "submit_content");
```

Comment: It’s actually `setAttribute` instead of `addAttribute`. I fixed that.

Comment: This one is not working.. what's the solution to this..??

setAttribute("event.stopPropagation()")

Answer (score 8):

```
document.getElementById("in1").setAttribute("name", "submit_content");
```

or using jQuery:

```
$("#in1").attr("name", "submit_content");
```